# PLY parse from a list of LexToken

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, lex, ply

I want to change my lexer to parse with a list of LexToken create by the lexer.
My lexer parse the code and create a list with all tokens type as CHAR and I want to change it to a list of token with type as LETTER.
(THIS IS AN EXAMPLE)
This is an example of what I want to do:

```
# My code to parse
code = "my text"

# My only token
tokens = ("CHAR",)

# I want to change all token CHAR to LETTER
t_CHAR = r'.{1}'

# My lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

lexer.input(code)

# My list of LexToken
tokens_list = []

# This change all token type to LETTER
for t in lexer:
    # t return LexToken object
    t.type = 'LETTER'

    tokens_list.append(t)

# My parser rules
# [...]
# [...]
# My parser build from a LexToken list
parser = yacc.yacc(myLexTokenList=tokens_list)

# Parse the code
parser.parse(code)
```

How I cant do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
code = "my text"
tokens = ("CHAR",)

def t_CHAR(t):
    r'.{1}'
    t.type = 'LETTER'

lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input(code)

parser = yacc.yacc()

# Parse the code
parser.parse(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, parser.parse can be used with tokenfunc argument

```
tokens = [...]

def token_func():
   if len(tokens):
       return tokens.pop(0)

parser = yacc.yacc()
parser.parse(code, tokenfunc = token_func)
```